# Extract text segments from data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have lot of sheets, and I need to remove text in middle of each cell

My data looks like:

```
2015-05-06T194803Z_1_LWD000Y24X6QH_RTRWNEV_B_3227-MEXICO-ALIENS-PHOTO
2015-05-06T222036Z_1_LWD0Y24Z6N9_RTRWNEV_B_3318-USA-POLICE-CHICAGO
2015-05-06T224129Z_1_LWD000Y2A56Y1_RTRWNEV_0_4601-IRAN-OIL-MARKET
```

I want this format:

```
Column A    Column B   Column C
5/6/2015    3227       MEXICO-ALIENS-PHOTO
5/6/2015    3318       USA-POLICE-CHICAGO   
5/6/2015    4601       IRAN-OIL-MARKET
```

Comment: how about a SUBSTITUTE command ?if the text was common replace it with " "

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the following formula in excel if the data you have shown is consistent.

For Column A use
`=LEFT(A1,10)`
*Comment: The first 10 digits represent the date*

For Column B use
`=MID(A1,FIND("_B_",A1)+3,4)`
*Comment: The `_B_` if it is consistently available in all the fields you can use that as a marker and extract the 4 digits*
**OR**
You can use the formula
`=MID(A1,46,4)`
*Comment: This formula just assumes that your 4 digit data is exactly 46 places from the beginning of the text*

For Column C use
`=MID(A1,FIND(K1,A1)+5,LEN(A1))`
*Comment: After extracting the previous four digits, the text is offset only by 5 places - provided it is consistent you can extract the text as well*